# AWGN channel outputs real numbers instead of complex

Tags: matlab

I get this error when I run my code in Matlab. But I can run example "Transmit a shortened RS-encoded, 256-QAM-modulated symbol stream through an AWGN channel" at link https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.rsencoder-class.html with no problem.

When I check values in variable chnData in my code, I see real numbers. When I check values in variable chan in the example code, I see complex numbers. What's wrong with my code?

PS: I am working on R2012b and Communication Toolbox version is 5.3.

Error message:

```
Error using comm.RectangularQAMDemodulator/step
Complexity mismatch with input 1; expected complex, got real.
Error in project (line 41)
            demData = step(qamDemodulator, chnData);
```

My code:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
enableRS = 1;
M = 16; % M-QAM
N = 15; % Reed-Solomon Coding : codelength
K = 11; % Reed-Solomon Coding : wordlength
EbNo = [-5:5]; % AWGN Channel : bit-to-noise energy
bps = log2(M); % AWGN Channel : bits per symbol
rsEncoder = comm.RSEncoder('CodewordLength', N, ...
                           'MessageLength',  K);
rsDecoder = comm.RSDecoder('CodewordLength', N, ...
                           'MessageLength',  K);
qamModulator = comm.RectangularQAMModulator('ModulationOrder', M, ...
                                            'NormalizationMethod', 'Average power');
qamDemodulator = comm.RectangularQAMDemodulator('ModulationOrder', M, ...
                                                'NormalizationMethod', 'Average power');
awgnChannel = comm.AWGNChannel('EbNo', EbNo, ...
                               'BitsPerSymbol', bps);
errorRate = comm.ErrorRate;
[H W] = size(EbNo);
errors = zeros(1,W);
for e = 1:W
    error = zeros(1,3);
    awgnChannel.EbNo = EbNo(e);
    if enableRS == 1
        while error(2) < 100 && error(3) < 1e7
             txData = randi([0 1], K, bps);
            encData = step(rsEncoder, bi2de(txData));
            modData = step(qamModulator, encData);
            chnData = step(awgnChannel, encData);
            demData = step(qamDemodulator, chnData);
            decData = step(rsDecoder, de2bi(demData));
             rxData = decData;
               error = step(errorRate, bi2de(txData), bi2de(rxData));
        end
    end
    errors(e) = error(1);
end
if enableRS == 1
    semilogy(EbNo, errors);
    grid;
    xlabel('Eb/No (db)');
    ylabel('Bit Error Rate');
    hold;
    uncoded = berawgn(EbNo, 'qam', M);
    semilogy(EbNo, uncoded);
end
```

Comment: AWGNChannel must be giving output complexity same as its input. It cannot add complexity to a signal. You need to check the data before AWGNChannel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake! It is fixed now.

```
modData = step(qamModulator, encData);
chnData = step(awgnChannel, encData); // Should have been modData
```